# Meteor Autoform: methodserver not called

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to use the quickform submit to server method and I don't think it's working. The console.log that I put inside the method seems to not be called when I press Submit.

Here's a demo for my problem.
https://github.com/afifsohaili/quickform-demo

Server.js:

```
Volunteer = new Mongo.Collection("volunteer");

if (typeof Schema === "undefined") Schema = {};
Schema.volunteer = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    label: "Name",
    max: 255,
    type: String
  },
  birthdate: {
    label: "Birthday / DD-MM-YYYY",
    type: String
  },
  mobile_number: {
    label: "Phone number",
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    label: "Email address",
    type: "email"
  },
  facebook_url: {
    label: "Facebook URL",
    optional: true,
    type: String
  },
  university: {
    label: "University",
    optional: true,
    type: String
  },
  occupation: {
    label: "Occupation",
    optional: true,
    type: String
  },
  male: {
    autoform: {
      class: "with-gap",
      falseLabel: "Female",
      trueLabel: "Male",
      type: "boolean-radios",
    },
    label: " ",
    type: Boolean
  },
  transport: {
    autoform: {
      type: "boolean-checkbox"
    },
    label: "I have my own transport",
    type: Boolean
  }
});

Meteor.methods({
  registerVolunteer: function(doc) {
    console.log(doc);
  }
});
```

Html:

```
<head>
  <title>test-quickform</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      {{> quickForm schema="Schema.volunteer" id="newVolunteerForm"
          type="method" meteormethod="registerVolunteer"
          buttonClasses="pink accent-3 waves-effect waves-light btn"
          buttonContent="Continue" }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: note: .scss has a dependency, just removed the import line and it compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

createdAt `type: "hidden"` still being validate on client and prevent method call due to no value. Try add `optional: true` and set the value on server.

BTW, createdAt attribute is missing on your question.

Comment: that's true. would you mind sharing how you debugged this?

Comment: open browser console, type `AutoForm.debug();` before click the submit button. It will show you debug message something like `Error in newVolunteerForm pre-submit validation Error: Created at is required(…)`

Answer (score 0):

Your form validation is failing, which prevent calling the "registerVolunteer". Check your schema

```
// Run "before.method" hooks                                                                                       // 14
    this.runBeforeHooks(this.insertDoc, function (doc) {                                                               // 15
      // Validate. If both schema and collection were provided, then we validate                                       // 16
      // against the collection schema here. Otherwise we validate against whichever                                   // 17
      // one was passed.                                                                                               // 18
      var valid = (c.formAttributes.validation === 'none') ||                                                          // 19
          c.formTypeDefinition.validateForm.call({                                                                     // 20
            form: c.formAttributes,                                                                                    // 21
            formDoc: doc,                                                                                              // 22
            useCollectionSchema: c.ssIsOverride                                                                        // 23
          });                                                                                                          // 24
                                                                                                                       // 25
      if (valid === false) {                                                                                           // 26
        c.failedValidation(); // <- Your code stops here                                                                                         // 27
      }
```